# how to install eapol_test in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, freeradius

I'm  tired  idea how to install this package eapol_test, I read online how I  can  make install it, but it didn't work for many time so  How can I Install the  eapol_test in Ubuntu in a simple and concise way ?
(My Ubuntu 20.04.3 )

Comment: Debian has a eapoltest package that contains `/usr/bin/eapol_test`, in all likelyhood the derivative called Ubuntu does so too.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it from universe repository for Ubuntu `hirsute`, `impish` and `jammy`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install eapoltest
```

You can build the package for all Ubuntu releases:

```
sudo apt install git libssl-dev devscripts pkg-config libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev
git clone --depth 1 --no-single-branch https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server.git
cd freeradius-server/scripts/ci/
./eapol_test-build.sh
cp ./eapol_test/eapol_test /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: My Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: @محمدمحمد You need to build the package.

Comment: // why the package is not build   ---
It is necessary to take 49.6 MB from the archives.
After this operation, 234 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Would you like to continue ? [Y / n] y
Cancelation.

Comment: @محمدمحمد Please update your system `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` then build the package (the last 5 lines in my answer)